# Cloud Storage Transfer Service from S3 stuck in "this transfer is starting"

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-transfer

A part of our application initiates transfers from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud Storage via the storage transfer service API. We've had this up and running successfully for several months until yesterday when our transfers stopped working. We can see a transfer was initiated in the console, but it hangs indefinitely with a single history item stating: "This transfer is starting..." We have a background process polling the transfer status which we see returning a status of "transfer_calculating"

In trying to debug this issue, we setup a transfer via the [storage console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/transfer). We used the same AWS access key id/secret access key used by our application, and the transfer completed successfully. This leads us to believe the issue is isolated to the transfer service API or our code that initiates the API call.

Transfer Job Code:

```
TransferJob tjob = new TransferJob()
    .setDescription(description)
    .setStatus('ENABLED')
    .setProjectId(transferGoogleProject)
    .setTransferSpec(
    new TransferSpec()
        .setGcsDataSink(new GcsData().setBucketName(googleStorageBucket))
        .setAwsS3DataSource(
        new AwsS3Data()
            .setBucketName(s3Bucket)
            .setAwsAccessKey(new AwsAccessKey().setAccessKeyId(transferAwsKey).setSecretAccessKey(transferAwsSecret)))
        .setObjectConditions(new ObjectConditions().setIncludePrefixes(s3Keys))
        .setTransferOptions(
        new TransferOptions()
            .setDeleteObjectsFromSourceAfterTransfer(false)
            .setOverwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink(true)
            .setDeleteObjectsUniqueInSink(false)))
    .setSchedule(
    new Schedule()
        .setScheduleStartDate(date)
        .setScheduleEndDate(date)
        .setStartTimeOfDay(time))

tjob = storagetransfer.transferJobs().create(tjob).execute()
```

Library configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev191-1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev26-1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-storagetransfer</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev3-1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

We've bumped the versions up 1.21.0 in our development environment but the transfers still get stuck at "This transfer is starting..."

At this point we're stuck, anyone else running into this issue?

Comment: We apologize for the difficulty and are investigating this issue. Could you please send your project IDs and exact queries to: gs-team@google.com so we can look into your exact case? Thanks!
-Mayur

Answer (score 3):

From feedback provided by @mayur-deshpande at Google (thanks!), our issue stems from the time value passed to setStartTimeOfDay() needing to be in UTC. Up to this point, we've used US/Pacific which is prescribed in  the following snippet from the [creating transfers development guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/storage-transfer/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/storagetransfer/samples/AwsRequester.java)

```
/**
 * Specify times below using US Pacific Time Zone.
 */
private static final String START_DATE = "YYYY-MM-DD";
private static final String START_TIME = "HH:MM:SS";
```

Due to the time difference, the time we sent in our request had already passed, so the transfer sat in started status until our time was hit the next day. We saw this happen as the requests did eventually complete.

The javadoc for setStartTime() of day does point out the need to use UTC:

```
/**
 * The time in UTC at which the transfer will be scheduled to start in a day. Transfers may start
 * later than this time. If not specified, transfers are scheduled to start at midnight UTC.
 * @param startTimeOfDay startTimeOfDay or {@code null} for none
 */
public Schedule setStartTimeOfDay(TimeOfDay startTimeOfDay)
```

The example code referenced above should reflect this requirement, so I'll file an issue in the github repo.

Also, since we are only doing one time transfers, we made sure to set our start time one minute in the future to account for subtle time differences between servers:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime().plusMinutes(1)
Date date = new Date().setDay(now.dayOfMonth).setMonth(now.monthOfYear).setYear(now.year)
TimeOfDay time = new TimeOfDay().setHours(now.hourOfDay).setMinutes(now.minuteOfHour).setSeconds(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the API the StartTimeOfDay is in reference of UTC (please see the API reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs#Schedule). The request you emailed to us specified an hour that was in the past based on UTC. Please specify a StartTimeOfDay in UTC. If you just want to start a one-off job run immediately, just leaving the StartTimeOfDay field empty would work.

Please also note that the Google Cloud UI lets customers specify a StartTimeOfDay in local timezone, which is different from the API.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, we were unaware of the ability to leave StartTimeOfDay empty for an immediate transfer (which is excatly what we want).

We've updated our code and tested it successfully. This is nice as it also eliminates any time differences between when we create/send the request and when the transfer service receives it. As noted in my answer below, we used US/Pacific based on sample code in the creating transfers development guide.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Storage Transfer Service to be very challenging to get working.  There were many nuances. It would be very helpful to clean up the doc and get all the info in one easy to find place in a clear way.

An overview for anyone after me:

1) Create a service account

2) Via IAM, give the service account the role Project->Editor

3) Start with the sample code on github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/storage-transfer/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/storagetransfer/samples/

- 3a) Only need to concern yourself three of the classes: AwsRequester,
  TransferJobUtils & RetryHttpInitializerWrapper

  3b) Create a Storagetransfer client, need the
  google-api-services-storagetransfer jar, to connect with your secret
  JSON file
- 3c) Create a TransferJob object to submit the job, this is where you
  set the projectId and Schedule where you will need to at least set
  the date and leave the time null for immediate submission but you do
  need to create a schedule

  3d) Create a TransferSpec object which will have the bulk of your
  configuration options. The mappings to the options are not clear. You
  will need to use the JSON API doc, https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec,
  and match the names in the Java API. At a minimum, you will want to
  populate: AWS bucket & credentials, GCS sink, etc...  The sample
  gives you this.  But you will also want to set
  ObjectConditions.setIncludePrefixes with a list of strings, the same 
  way you via the UI.

4) Don't even bother trying to make sense of the main page, cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-client, read it only once. Its just not that helpful for really making it work.

HTH?